# OData cast binary data before filtering

Tags: c#, odata, azure-mobile-services

So,

I am trying to use OData's filtering and specifically the greater than operator on a binary field. 
I want the field to be cast to Int64 before comparison, but cant find a way to.

The example request i have come up so far :

```
http://URLTOCONTROLLER?$select=__version&$orderby=__version
&$filter=__version ge cast(binary'00000000000009FD', 'Edm.Int64')
```

This throws an incompatible types Edm.Binary and Edm.Int64 error.

What i would like to do is :

```
http://URLTOCONTROLLER?$select=__version&$orderby=__version
&$filter=cast(__version,'Edm.Int64') ge cast(binary'00000000000009FD', 'Edm.Int64')
```

But this throw an error that the function cast is not implemented.

Any helps ? Anyone tried to compare a binary field on db as if it was int?